# Twig render(controller(...)): accessing parent-blocks

Tags: css, symfony, twig

First: I'm new to Symfony2, just writing my first project.

I am writing a gallery which I want to use in several Symfony-Projects.

My general Idea is to have the entire gallery in a bundle. The API should just be a single ContollerAction from the gallery-Controller.
I want to include the gallery in a website by calling

WebsiteTemplate:

```
{{ render(controller( "MyGalleryBundle:Gallery:build")) }}
```

This WebsiteTemplate is extending from a baseTemplate with blocks for css, js, etc...

BaseTemplate:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        [...]

        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

        {% block head %}
            {% block css %}{% endblock %}
            {% block js %}{% endblock %}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block menu %}{% endblock %}
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

It seems, that everything is working fine (html-structure is rendered in the right place) but the css isn't beeing putted into the head of the html-file, but instead right in the html scope, which causes that no css is beeing parsed.

I was trying to achieve it by simply calling the blocks from the bastTemplate like so:

```
[ setting some twig variables ]

{% block head %}
    {% block css %}
    {% stylesheets 
        'bundles/doublebeatsgallery/css/base.css'
        'bundles/doublebeatsgallery/css/picture.css'
        'bundles/doublebeatsgallery/css/page.css'
        output="bundles/doublebeatsgallery/css/compiled/main.css"
    %}
        <link type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet">
    {% endstylesheets %}


    <script type="text/css">
        {% set tpl = galleryConfig.look.template %}

        .tmpl_box:hover {
            z-index: 5;
            margin-left: -{{(tpl.popUpWidth - tpl.width)/2}}px;
            margin-top: -{{(tpl.popUpHeight - tpl.height)/2}}px;

        }

    </script>   
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}


    <div id="galleryHeader" class="galleryBaseContainer backA">
        <div id="pContainer"><span>{{selectedGallery}}</span></div>
    </div>
    [... rest of html ]
```

Comment: Can it be that the render function is becausing calling a new Controller with a new scope blocks the access to parent blocks?

Comment: That's about it Martin. `render` blocks could be independently served by a caching-proxy like varnish. This way they wouldn't know anything about the master request and might be entirely served from cache. You can easily add an additional `render(controller('MyGalleryBundle:Gallery:css'))` block to solve this problem.

Comment: @nifr I don't have an idea of how this action should look like! Or how this would solve the problem. Could you please give me a small example?! That would be great!

Comment: just let a second action create the template for the `<script>`-tag which styles the gallery. Then render that in a separate `render` tag. You can do so for the rendering of the menu respectively. got the idea ?

Comment: Yeah but then i have still the same problem of that they wouldn't be parsed o the head of the file! (or: to the blocks of the parent) ?!

Comment: If you include the `render` method in the `{% block css %}` this will work out nicely. Why again do you need access to the "parent" block ? If you need to access variables thats a clear sign for a code-smell -> you're putting too much logic into your templates.

Comment: Ah i got your idea.... I want for future projects to keep the efforts to implement the gallery as small as possible as i don't want to work each time again with the code i wrote. So i was looking for a one line api to include the gallery what i thought might work withe render function of twig. But then i have to access the parent blocks of the gallery template which would be those of the website. You got my idea? Is this reasonable?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47687/discussion-between-nifr-and-martin)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to override the `head` block itself, just the inner `css` block. Not sure if this solves your problem, but you could give it a try.

Comment: Well, I tried first without the head block. And then thought maybe it could be the reason why it didn't work and then tried like this, but its not working neither...